# How are ray-finned and lobe-finned fish related in terms of their evolutionary history?

Tags: evolution, zoology, phylogenetics, marine-biology, vertebrates

I'm trying to trace human evolution back to the first eukaryotic cells (as a tool to research the evolution of various bodily systems), and I understand that lobe-finned fishes are considered a key transitional group between early fishes and the first tetrapods. However, I'm struggling to understand the relationship between ray-finned fishes and lobe-finned fishes and how they fit into the larger picture of evolutionary history. I’ve tried using google, Wikipedia, and YouTube, but I can’t seem to find a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

[should possibly be a comment but can't embed images there]

The rather clear consensus is that tetrapods are a subordinate group within lobe-finned fish, which is a sister group to ray-finned fish. See diagram below from [here](https://bmcecolevol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2148-10-21). This should be apparent from the [wiki article on lobe-finned fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcopterygii).

Just to be clear, yes, we're all fish from a cladistic point of view.

[image: high-level view of sarcopterygii and actinopterygii evolutionary history].

Comment: What was their common ancestor like?

Comment: @SeanHolm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osteichthyes

Comment: i loved those armored fish as a kid!

Comment: @shigeta [my personal favorite](https://coastal-watershed.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/stained-stickleback-998x1024.jpg)- phenotypic variation of the armor character!